# knitting R markdown to a word document

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to knit an R markdown file to word document and I get this message. How can I sort that out?

processing file: OSTEOTOMY-ACL-STATS-SECOND-TRIAL.Rmd

output file: OSTEOTOMY-ACL-STATS-SECOND-TRIAL.knit.md

Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting docx output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

always_allow_html: true

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.

Execution halted